# How to install jekyll to a Docker image?

Tags: ruby, docker, rubygems, dockerfile, docker-image

I'd like to generate a docker image that has the command `jekyll` available.

I generated a `Dockerfile` with the following content:

```
# https://hub.docker.com/_/ruby/
FROM ruby:slim

RUN gem install jekyll
```

Unfortunately throws an error:

```
ERROR:  Error installing jekyll:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /usr/local/bundle/gems/ffi-1.9.10/ext/ffi_c
/usr/local/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160615-7-12pthrg.rb extconf.rb
checking for ffi.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/local/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-ffi_c-dir
    --without-ffi_c-dir
    --with-ffi_c-include
    --without-ffi_c-include=${ffi_c-dir}/include
    --with-ffi_c-lib
    --without-ffi_c-lib=${ffi_c-dir}/lib
    --with-libffi-config
    --without-libffi-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:587:in `try_cpp'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:1091:in `block in have_header'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:942:in `block in checking_for'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:320:in `open'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:350:in `block in postpone'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:320:in `open'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:346:in `postpone'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:941:in `checking_for'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:1090:in `have_header'
    from extconf.rb:16:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /usr/local/bundle/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0-static/ffi-1.9.10/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/bundle/gems/ffi-1.9.10 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/bundle/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0-static/ffi-1.9.10/gem_make.out
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To diagnose the issue you can jump into the container and dig into what's causing the issue.

```
$ docker run -ti --rm ruby:slim /bin/bash
root@bda37983a585:/# gem install jekyll
# ...
```

Alternatively there is always the jekyll docker image:
https://hub.docker.com/u/jekyll/

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

There are a few requirements you’ll need to add to your DockerFile before use Jekyll.

- Ruby
- RubyGems
- NodeJS
- Python 2.7

So, your `DockerFile` should look like this:

```
FROM ruby:2.1
MAINTAINER nobody@test.com

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y \
    node \
    python-pygments \
  && apt-get clean \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/

RUN gem install \
  github-pages \
  jekyll \
  jekyll-redirect-from \
  kramdown \
  rdiscount \
  rouge

VOLUME /src
EXPOSE 4000

WORKDIR /src
ENTRYPOINT ["jekyll"]
```

Comment: I realized that the ruby-package is quite large. Now I used `jekyll/jekyll` as Mr Gravity proposed.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a multi arch image. No Pi no M1.